# How Sqlbrite database uses schedulers

Tags: sqlite, sqlbrite, sqldelight

I am new to the sqlbrite database, while creating a database wrapper it asks for the rxjava `Schedulers`

What i want to know is

> Is that schedulers which i passed in the wrapper is used to run `insert`,`delete`,`update` etc. query

or

> Is it only used for the QueryObservable i.e createQuery for observing database table.

Can anyone help me with this?